# List of Original Esperanto Works

Tags: literature

Excluding magazines, can you provide a list of original (non-translated) Esperanto literature? It may be translated from Esperanto to other languages but the original work should have been in Esperanto.

Comment: FWIW, I have written a number of original articles in Esperanto. You can view them here: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/dosierujo-artikoloj-en-esperanto.html

Comment: @MikeJones That link seems no longer valid. Is there a new URL for that content?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://esperanto.net/literaturo/) old but extensive list should be useful for you. You can also consult the voluminous [encyclopedia](http://www.mondialbooks.com/enciklopedio/index.html) by G. Sutton.

Answer (score 2):

You can also refer to the Esperanto Wikipedia, which has a long article about [Esperanto Literature](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanta_literaturo).